# Compute oscillator frequency without using float or uint64 types in C

Tags: c, frequency

I have a 32.768 kHz oscillator which produces a 1-Hz pulse. I'm measuring this pulse with a 40MHz clock. I am trying to measure the actual frequency of the oscillator by comparing the expected results with the obtained one.

- I cannot change the period that I'm measuring, it has to be 1-Hz (1s).
- I cannot use float, double or types larger than uint32.
- I also need the first digit after the integer part (like 32768.1 Hz).

Without the constraints the solution would be like:

```
computedFreq = (uint32) ( (float32)32768u /  ( ( (float32)measuredPeriod / (float32)40,000,000 ) / (float32)10u ) );
```

or

```
computedFreq = ( 32768*10*40,000,000 ) / measuredPeriod;
```

So for a measured period of 40,008,312 the result will be 327611.

How can this be achieved while satisfying the constraints?

Comment: Use 2 uint32 to emulate a uint64 and work in dHez

Comment: What is the possible range of `measurePeriod`?

Comment: @user694733 40,000,000 +/- 10,000.

Comment: 40MHz to sample a 1Hz signal.....at least too oversampled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that measured range goes up to 40010000 Hz, while you are only interested in 20000 Hz range. So the solution is to limit the range.

You can do this with linear interpolation using 2 points.

1. Select 2 input values. Min/max points might do:

   ```
   inMin = 40,000,000 - 10,000
   inMax = 40,000,000 + 10,000
   ```
2. Precalculate respective output values using your formula (values here are rough values, calculate your own): You can store these as constants in your code.

   ```
   outMin = ( 32768*10*40,000,000 ) / inMin = 327761 
   outMax = ( 32768*10*40,000,000 ) / inMax = 327598
   ```

   Notice how max is smaller than min, due the nature of your formula. This is important when selecting types below.
3. Use linear interpolation to calculate result using both previous points:

   ```
   out = (in - inMin) * (outMax - outMin) / (inMax - inMin) + outMin
   ```

   You have to use signed integers for this, because `(outMax - outMin)` is negative.

   Upper limit of the multiplication is `(inMax - inMin) * (outMax - outMin)`, which should fit into int32.

You can pick any 2 points, but you should pick ones that will not produce too big values to overflow on multiplication. Also, if points are too near each other, answer may be less accurate.

If you you have extra precision to spare, you could use bigger multiplier than 10 on outMin/outMax and round afterwards to keep more precision.

Comment: I changed the formula to generic form of interpolation, so that it's useful elsewhere too.

Comment: I will try it and get back to you, thank you for the suggestion. Also the value are inverted because a lower frequency in the 32.768kHz oscillator means that the 1-HZ pulse takes more than 1 second and the other way around.

Comment: @AlexandruCimpanu Ok. Just to note, I added edit on data types, which is important. It's possible to do this with unsigned integers too,  but I won't add it unless it's needed.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `32768 * 10 * 40000000 = 3200000000 * 2^12`.

You can use this fact in order to approximate the frequency as follows:

```
computedFreq = (3200000000/measuredPeriod) << 12;
```

---

UPDATE:

I understand that `39990000 <= measuredPeriod <= 40010000`.

A better way to approximate the frequency under this restriction would be:

```
computedFreq = 327761-(measuredPeriod-39990000)/122;
```

Comment: I'm not sure that helps much. Considering the range of his values, and that he can only use integer math, only possible results are `327680` and `323584`.

Comment: @user694733: Assuming that `computedFreq` and `measuredPeriod` are integers, it **is** integer-math. And I don't quite understand why you think that the only possible results are `327680` and `323584`.

Comment: Problem is the limited range: `3200000000 / (40000000 - 10000)  = 80` and `3200000000 / (40000000 + 10000)  = 79`.

Comment: @user694733: Well, I wasn't aware of this limit. In that case, the OP may as well use a lookup table of 20000 entries (32 bits per entry, or with some effort - even 20 bits per entry).

Comment: @user694733: Alternatively (as I have added in the question), `computedFreq` decreases by 1 approximately every time `measuredPeriod` increases by 122. The error here is at most 1.